# mysql FULLTEXT search multiple words

Tags: php, mysql, search

I've never really heard a straight answer on this one, I just need to FULLTEXT search a couple columns with multiple words "Firstname Lastname"

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 
                    patient_db 
                    WHERE MATCH ( Name, id_number )
                    AGAINST ('% $term %' IN BOOLEAN MODE);");
```

But it fails to run the query if I enter more than one word here.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 
         patient_db WHERE 
         MATCH ( Name, id_number ) 
         AGAINST ('+first_word +second_word +third_word' IN BOOLEAN MODE);");
```

and if you want to do exact search:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                  FROM patient_db 
                  WHERE MATCH ( Name, id_number ) 
                  AGAINST ('"exact phrase"' IN BOOLEAN MODE);");
```

Comment: Can somebody enlighten me if there is also a limit of how many terms you can search in 1 MATCH AGAINST query? In this answer's example, you have third_word which is also working in my own query but when i put the +fourth_word & even if it exist in the columns, it does return empty result.

Comment: "exact phrase" does not mean exact phrase without any sign (+/-) it will be treated as an OR. there is no exact phrase in full text search, only all words, some words, none of the words.

Comment: This are  changed over period of 5 years

Comment: @Gamesh fulltext search does have "exact phrase" searching as long as you wrap the phrase in double quotes. I'm using it now on one of my projects.

Comment: @Chris you're right it does, not sure what i was thinking writing that:

`A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (") characters matches only rows that contain the phrase literally, as it was typed. The full-text engine splits the phrase into words and performs a search in the FULLTEXT index for the words. Nonword characters need not be matched exactly: Phrase searching requires only that matches contain exactly the same words as the phrase and in the same order. For example, "test phrase" matches "test, phrase".`

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * 
FROM patient_db 
WHERE MATCH ( Name, id_number ) 
      AGAINST ("Firstname Lastname" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

The double-quotes are important. This looks for literally the phrase "Firstname Lastname".
You don't need the percentage signs.

If you look for "Firstname blahblahblah Lastname blahblah", the `AGAINST()` clause has to look like this:

```
AGAINST ('+Firstname +Lastname' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Have look at the [MySQL docs on full text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html) for more info.

Another thing: why do you have the `id_number` column in your match?

Comment: Hi sorry I posted that before I went to bed last night.  This is still not working for me, I only have one search field called $term and both the First and Last names are in the same mySQL column