# PHP - Search multiple words for search terms

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm setting up a PHP function to return a result from the database based on what the user is looking for by a search bar.

In the database I have this:
"**skirt blue red**"

In search bar, if the user writes "**skirt red**" the result should come out, as `"like '%skirt%red%'"`

I am trying in this way but it doesn't work.

```php
    if (isset($conds['searchterm'])) {
                $search1 = explode(" ", ($conds['searchterm']));
                 { 
        $cond_name1 = $search1[0];
            $cond_name2 = $search1[1];
            $cond_name3 = $search1[2];
            $cond_name4 = $search1[3];
            $cond_name5 = $search1[4];

                    
        $this->db->group_start();
        $this->db->like( 'table.title', $cond_name1 );
        $this->db->and_like( 'table.title', $cond_name2 );
        $this->db->and_like( 'table.title', $cond_name3 );
            $this->db->and_like( 'table.title', $cond_name4 );
            $this->db->and_like( 'table.title', $cond_name5 );
        this->db->group_end();
                }
            }
```

What is wrong?

Honestly I'm stuck on this.

Comment: This code has syntax errors

Comment: The title can't be like skirt AND like red

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717312/mysql-fulltext-search-multiple-words